# Is there a way to make this method suitable to override?

Tags: c#, methods, botframework, overriding

i have implemented a transcription feature inside my bot based on the Microsoft Bot Framework v4 (c#). For the storage type i used the Azure Table Storage. Everything works like expected. From there i want that the bot gets the access credentials to the storage strictly from the configuration tab in the App Service.

But then after i implemented this, it says that my method isnt suitable to override anymore.

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(IConfiguration configuration, ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // First, we use the dispatch model to determine which cognitive service (LUIS or QnA) to use.
            var recognizerResult = await _botServices.Dispatch.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
            var topIntent = recognizerResult.GetTopScoringIntent();

            // Next, we call the dispatcher with the top intent.
            await DispatchToTopIntentAsync(configuration, turnContext, topIntent.intent, recognizerResult, cancellationToken);
        }
```

[image]

This Error appears after i add the configuration parameter in the OnMessageActivityAsync method. But i need the parameter there because i make use of it inside the DispatchToTopIntentAsync:

```cs
// Suche nach der richtigen KnowledgeBase
        private async Task DispatchToTopIntentAsync(IConfiguration configuration, ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, string intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            switch (intent)
            {
                case "q_SEKAI_Allgemein":
                    await ProcessSEKAI_AllgemeinAsync(configuration, turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                case "q_SEKAI_HomeOffice":
                    await ProcessSEKAI_HomeOfficeAsync(configuration, turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                case "q_SEKAI_MixedReality":
                    await ProcessSEKAI_MixedRealityAsync(configuration, turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;

                default:
                    // Wird ausgeführt, wenn keine KnowledgeBase gefunden wird
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}.");

                    await TableStorageEintrag(configuration, turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

In this part the bot decids which KnowledgeBase fits the best for further work.

But how can i fix this issue? Feel free to ask if you need more informations. I will then edit my post asap :)

[image]

(This screenshot refers to a answer from this post)

Comment: if `IConfiguration` is a user-defined interface, then use the full namespace path to it, as there is `IConfiguration` interface in .NET, which might be the cause of your issue.

Comment: _"Is there a way to make this method suitable to override?"_ -- that method? No. The override _must_ have _exactly_ the same signature as the original virtual method declaration. See duplicate. Are there other ways to implement something similar? Maybe. Depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change the parameters of a base virtual class and expect to override it.
The correct signature is as follows, given on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.activityhandler.onmessageactivityasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)

```
protected virtual Task OnMessageActivityAsync(
    ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Can you inject IConfigration at the consturctor of your class

```
private readonly IConfiguration _iConfiguration;
// Inject it here
public ConstructorOfYourClass(IConfiguration iConfiguration) {
    _iConfiguration = iConfiguration;
}

protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(
    ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        .......
    // Use it here
    await DispatchToTopIntentAsync(_iConfiguration, turnContext, topIntent.intent, recognizerResult, cancellationToken);
}
```